# php true method to use mysqli connection everywhere

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a MySQLi connection object to connect to mysql 
as this :

```
require_once('config.php');


//new mysqli object
$mysqli = new mysqli(MYSQL_HOSTNAME, MYSQL_USERNAME, MYSQL_PASSWORD, MYSQL_DATABASE);

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}
```

and I've included this file into any files to have connection

Is it right way?
I think in my every files , I will have new connection to MySQL.

Comment: I think is way simpler to place connection in a file and `require_once()` when you need connection

Comment: Thank you.Yes I'm using it.But I need to know I will have multiple connection object or not.

Comment: You can have one connection and make as many operation as you need

Comment: So,I always have a object .not duplicate,right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Php does not have control over how many connections you will have. Mysql manages the pool internally and will allocate connections according to the `max_connections` parameter for example (not sure of exact parameter name).

Creating 10 connection objects does not mean having 10 opened connections.

Comment: Thanks.Is there any example?what is the standard ?how big projects like Joomla has done it?

Comment: should I put $mysqli->close(); after the end?

Comment: Hi. I ignore how Joomla is doing it, but you should not worry about this parameter. You have to know what is the average time of usage of each of your script so you can setup the timeout of the connection in accordance. Too high timeout value makes connection pool saturated quickly, too low makes connection lost warnings. Your server capacity should also influence the max_connection params value you should setup. Don't worry, mysql is doing it well! Also, just for you to know, each script being independant they will unallocate the memory so the connection will be closed anyway.

Comment: thank you for those information